# Can I send messages from LORIOT to an HTTP web server?

Tags: lora, lorawan, https

I actually send data packet from LORIOT and TTN to Cayenne.
I would understand if is possible to send instead data from Loriot or TTN to my custom http web server, if there is any procedure around explaining how to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On TTN console:

- create a new application
- within the application select "integration > webhooks"
- finally specify the URL of you application server
  For more details please check the [this](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/applications/http/) link.

On Loriot console:

- create a new application
- within the application select "output > new output"
- select HTTPS
- finally specify the URL of you application server
  For more details please check [this](https://docs.loriot.io/display/LNS/HTTP+PUSH) link: